# problem in implementing google authenticator app in c++

Tags: multi-factor-authentication, sha, hmac, c++, totp

i am trying to implement google Authenticator mechanism in c++.
i always get different OTP than that of google authenticator.

i wonder why ?

1 - i searched and found that google uses HMAC-SHA1 algorithm. but i am suspecious because :

- almost all articles i have read are old. seems irrelevent.
- i found that google authenticator code is now private before it was
  open source. so am afraid google might changed the algorithim used
- i found that SHA1 is no longer secure. some people managed to make
  SHA1-collision. i would be surprized if google still uses it instead of
  other more secure algorithms like SHA256,SHA512.

if you have any information regarding that, please inform me.

2 - i am sure my code is correct.

- because i compared the output Hash value to automatically generated one
  in this website, and they always match.
  the website : https://www.liavaag.org/English/SHA-Generator/HMAC/
- because code is pretty simple!

here's the code :

```
/*****************************************************************************************/
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "SHA1.h"
#include "HMAC_SHA1.h"

using namespace std;

void IntegerToString(time_t epochTime, BYTE timeAsString[] , int length);
int TimeLength(time_t epochTime);

int main(void)
{
    CHMAC_SHA1 sha1;
    int one,two,three,four;
    time_t result = time(nullptr);
    result = (long long)floor(result/30);
    cout << result <<endl;

    int offset;
    int truncatedHash;
    int finalOTP;

    BYTE key[33] = "atoqb4y572clkhj2sls5h72a76cnyzpe";
    int key_len = 33; /*32 + null terminator*/

    int text_len = TimeLength(result);
    //cout << text_len << endl;
    BYTE text[text_len+1];
    IntegerToString(result , text , text_len);
    text[text_len] = '\0';

    //printf("%s",text);

    /*the digest is always 20 bytes long*/
    BYTE digest[20] = {0};

    sha1.HMAC_SHA1(text,text_len,key,key_len-1,digest);

    printf("0x");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
    {
        printf("%x",(int)digest[i]);
    }

        offset = digest[19] & 0xf;
    
        one   = (digest[offset+0] & 0x7f) << 24;
        two   = (digest[offset+1] & 0xff) << 16;
        three = (digest[offset+2] & 0xff) << 8;
        four  = (digest[offset+3] & 0xff);
        truncatedHash = one | two | three | four;
        finalOTP = (truncatedHash % (1000000));

        cout << "\nyour OTP : " << finalOTP << endl;
    return 0;
}

void IntegerToString(time_t epochTime, BYTE timeAsString[] , int length)
{
    time_t reverse = 1; /*to hold zeros*/
    int i = 0;

    while(epochTime >= 1) /*reverse : 1000 -> 10001*/
    {
        reverse = reverse*10+epochTime%10;
        epochTime = epochTime / 10;
        //cout << epochTime << "*" << reverse <<endl;
    }

    while(reverse != 1)
    {
        timeAsString[i] = (reverse%10 +'0');
        reverse = reverse / 10;
        //cout << i << timeAsString[i] << "#" << reverse << endl;
        i++;
    }
}

int TimeLength(time_t epochTime)
{
    int counter = 0;

    while(epochTime)
    {
        epochTime = epochTime / 10;
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

please help.

Comment: This is a programming question, which makes it relevant to [so]. But as the question is right now, it's too low quality to be migrated. Please [edit] your question to format it better. Use the preview to see if formatting works as expected.

Comment: now cool ? if any thing ambigous ask me please.

Comment: Have you read the relevant standards [RFC6238](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238) and [RFC4226](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4226)?

Comment: yes i did. RFC4226 says google uses HMAC-SHA1.

Answer (score 1):

The key you use `atoqb4y572clkhj2sls5h72a76cnyzpe` does not seem to be in **hex** format.
You should be using hex (hex of your string is `04dd00f31dfe84b51d3a92e5d3ff40ff84dc65e4` If you need to use **base32**, you need to convert it to **hex** first

Answer (score 0):

This repo works out perfectly: https://github.com/RavuAlHemio/cpptotp

Just tested.

steps on ubuntu:

git clone https://github.com/RavuAlHemio/cpptotp.git

cd cpptotp/

mkdir build

cd build/

cmake ..

make

./gauche

Input your key